# Why am I not getting any input from this slurm job?

Tags: slurm

I am in a distributed and parallel computing class and we have to log into the Alabama Supercomputer and run a hello world for Open MP. I run it and the program compiles but there is no text in the output file other than data about the run time. What am I doing wrong? I compile it to an executable that I then put in the .sh file. Is this wrong?

My c file and my .sh file look like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

void Hello(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int  thread_count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

#   pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count)
    Hello();

    return 0;

}

void Hello(void){

    int my_rank = omp_get_thread_num();
    int thread_count = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("Hello from thread %d of %d\n", my_rank, thread_count);

}
```

```
#!/bin/sh
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=15
./OpenMPHello
```

Why does it run in the system but produce no output?

Comment: This is not ```batch-file```, batch is Windows only. Linux (or ```.sh```) is batch script.

Comment: please provide your slurm submission line